# Generate Image jpg with text in Php

Tags: php, html

How can I generate a image with text?

Exemple: [www.7apps.me](http://www.7apps.me)

I want to insert a Name and the website generate a random image with the Name that I have put.

Comment: Can you please post your php script here?

Comment: Now i'm not at home,  but my php script not work... i will use a new script with your help

Comment: Which php library you are using GD library or imagemagick?

Comment: You have to post your code

Comment: I'm noob in php and i think that you can help me with a php cript or a link tutorial how to make a script like www.7apps.me

Comment: My code not work, because is for Android application, but i try to convert in Php,but now work, can you help me with a php script or link tutorial?

Comment: @GeorgeDates We just want to see what you have tried that is not working.

Comment: Inow i'm not at home, i'm on my phone and i can't post the code

Comment: Delete the question .Post when you have code

Comment: He is just asking for demos or ressources, we don't need his code.

Comment: On your example there is no text in the images, that's only a HTML tag under the image. Do you want to add text **inside** the JPG image? A text in a image is called a **watermark** when it's about adding a brand or a copyright.

Answer (score -1):

- What is PHP ?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)

> the language's name [is] the recursive acronym PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor

- What are you trying to do ?

You are trying to generate an image with an hypertext preprocessor

---

That's not the easiest way.

You can go for PHP or JavaScript and generate SVG.

Example :

```js
function addText() {
  var txt = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
  txt.setAttribute("x",150);
  txt.setAttribute("y",100);
  txt.setAttribute("font-family","Verdana");
  txt.setAttribute("font-size","55");
  txt.innerHTML = "My Name";
  document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(txt);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="addText()">Add some text</button>
<br>
<svg id="mySVG" height="200" width="500">
  <rect fill="#73BAF0" height="200" width="500"></rect>
  <text x="175" y="50" font-family="Verdana" font-size="25" color="black">SVG DEMO</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: But how i can auto save ny new image in the serve? Images/generated/newimage.jpg ?

Comment: you can't, that's an image on the client side (html / JavaScript). For image generation server-side, I can't help, I never tried